# Simple JS Function not running and giving inappropriate error

Tags: javascript, function

Following is a simple example where I expect the output to be 2 alerts of value 10 and 20. However I am getting error. Why is that?

```html
<script>
var a = 10
(function alpha(){
alert(a); 
a = 20;
alert (a);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Uh, have you tried putting a semicolon after `var a = 10` ?

Comment: Yep, semicolon fixes it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the semicolon so that 10 isn't called as a function:

```js
var a = 10; // <=== add a semicolon here!
(function alpha() {
  alert(a);
  a = 20;
  alert(a);
})();
```

Javascript usually ignores the lack of semicolons. But there are cases where semicolons are extremely important, like in here, 10 is being called a function due to the parenthesis next to it:

```
var a = 10( function alpha(){} )();
```

Which is why to avoid encountering this kind of problem in the future, make it a hobby to add semicolons whether or not it is necessary.

Some JavaScript coding standards lets you omit semicolons at ends of line but the trick is you then have to put one at the start of most lines starting with an opening parenthesis of square bracket.